# Github API sort by latest followers

Tags: ruby, github-api

I am trying to get some data from Github API.

I've almost finished project but I need also last 5 user following me.

How I can get this? Can not find any solution on official documentation also google.

Thanks a lot

Comment: For a certain user you can try:   query {
  user(login:"githubID"){
    followers(last:5){
      edges{
        node{
          avatarUrl
          company
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Github GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), you can use `followers(last: 5)` in `viewer` if you want to get the last 5 followers of the authenticated user :

```graphql
{
  viewer {
    followers(last: 5) {
      nodes {
        login
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?payload=%7B%0A%20%20viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20followers(last%3A%205)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Or for a specific user :

```graphql
{
  user(login: "bertrandmartel") {
    followers(last: 5) {
      nodes {
        login
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?payload=%7B%0A%20%20user(login%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20followers(last%3A%205)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

You can also use API v3 with [/users/:user/followers](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/followers/#list-followers-of-a-user) but you would need to perform 2 or 3 requests:

- call https://api.github.com/users/:user/followers and extract `Link` header to get the last page, check [Travesing pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/)
- call https://api.github.com/users/:user/followers?page=X where X is the last page
- if there is not enough followers (< 5 items on the last page) you will need to request the previous one (last page - 1)