# Github Dashboard-Feed via API or RSS?

Tags: github, github-api

When loading the github.com page, I see a dashboard feed showing a list of "pushed" / "starred" updates for all of my followed repos.

When checking the Network tab on Chrome, I can see that this feed comes from this endpoint:

```
https://github.com/dashboard-feed
```

How do I get this data via the GitHub API? Is it also available via RSS?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way to extract the data?

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Rahul's reply which is very close, I did some googling and found this [article on how to build a python crawler for Github's API](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-python-crawler-to-get-activity-stream-with-github-api-d1e9f5831d88) which mentioned this recent events endpoint...

https://api.github.com/users/headwinds/received_events

...which lists the star events in order and you could use that rebuild a dashboard replacing the username.

Comment: Note that this endpoint doesn't list `X started following you` for instance, so I also used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49476243).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be available via RSS because to access this type of endpoint it requires authentication.

So what I think is, you can create your own activity feed with the help of individual RSS feeds (Atom feeds in case of GitHub) of the people's activity you want to get notified.

> For example see codeSTACKr's RSS feed: https://github.com/codeSTACKr.atom

You can also use this API `https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/following` to get all the following people (so you don't have to add individual user names without authentication).

> For example see codeSTACKr's following list: https://api.github.com/users/codeSTACKr/following